# How to only update some part of elements in ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using ng-repeat in a table,and I want to use post method to get data from server,and update the var **arry** and angularjs will update ; however the text input also been updated,but i don't want to update the text.How should i do?

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
    <script src="js/angular.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="formController">
<table border='1' cellpadding=2 cellspacing=2>
    <tr ng-repeat="a in array.Ip">
        <td>{{a.name}}</td>
        <td>{{a.price}}</td>
        <td>{{a.count}}</td>
        <td><input type="text"></td>//This should not be updated!
        <td><button>Add</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
<script>
    var app = angular.module('app', []);
    app.controller('formController', function($scope) {
        $scope.array = {
           TotalFinished : '12',
           TotalUnFinished : '13',
           Cpu : '14',
           Memory :'15',
           Ip : [{
                name : 'AAA',
                price : '20',
                count : '2'
                }, {
                name : 'BBB',
                price : '50',
                count : '1'
                }]
        };
       setInterval(function(){
             $scope.$apply(updatedata);
           },1000);


        var updatedata = function(){
            $scope.array ={
                TotalFinished : '14',
                TotalUnFinished : '13',
                Cpu : '14',
                Memory :'15',
                Ip : [{
                    name : 'CCC',
                    price : '20',
                    count : '2'
                }, {
                    name : 'DDDD',
                    price : '50',
                    count : '1'
                }]
            }; // 表格数据
            };
    });

</script>
```

Comment: may be help u http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35694474/editing-an-item-from-ng-repeat/35694712#35694712

Comment: Try using a model value in your input text box.

Comment: Hi,dishwasherWithProgrammingSkill.What i should bind the text to,different trs have different text.this text is not a member of the array,if i bind the text to a member of the array,it will be updated;

Comment: which value are your trying to add to your text box from the controller?

Answer (score 1):

You can use model value in the text box.

```
<tr ng-repeat="a in array.Ip">
    <td>{{a.name}}</td>
    <td>{{a.price}}</td>
    <td>{{a.count}}</td>
    <td><input type="text" ng-model='a.value'></td>
    <td><button>Add</button></td>
</tr>
```

And in your controller add value property to the Ip Array

```
for(var i=0;i<$scope.array.Ip;i++){
      $scope.array.Ip[i].value = '';
}
```

That way any change in your text box is tracked by angular $watch function. And when ever your array value changes in the ng-repeat, the value in the text box will be grabbed from the new scope variable you created.

The reason it did not work the way you intended before is because ng-repeat is a directive and when ever the scope value for your array changes it re-renders the entire `<td>` panels and without scope value assigned to your text box it will get rendered without any values.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks !But if do like  <input type="text" ng-model='model.value'> ,every text will bind to the same model,when i input to a text all texts' value changed. I want all texts are  independent;When a button be clicked,i can get the value of the text and {{a.name}} which in the same tr with the button.

Comment: I have updated my answer to work with your array. You will need to add an extra property in the Ip array. There might be a better solution for it though.

Comment: Thanks,for(var i=0;i<$scope.array.Ip;i++){
      $scope.array.Ip[i].value = '';
}